# Inject multiple remote EJBs in bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

In Java EE, if I have an interface:

```
@Remote
public interface MetaService {
    ServiceData get();
}
```

And I have, in an ear 2 implementations:

```
@Stateless
public class Service1MetaService implements Calculator {
    @Override
    public ServiceData get() {...}
}
```

```
@Stateless
public class Service2MetaService implements Calculator {
    @Override
    public ServiceData get() {...}
}
```

I can create a bean, where:

```
@Stateless
public class View {
    @Inject
    private Instance<MetaService> metaServices;

    ...
}
```

And in `View`, the field `metaServices` will have the 2 implementations of `MetaService`.

I'd like similar functionality with remote beans.

So let's say, I have the above interface and implementations, but the packaging is different.

In `base.jar` I have the `MetaService` interface. This is packaged will all the subsequent applications mentioned below.

In `a.ear` I have the `Service1MetaService` implementation, while in `b.ear` I have the `Service2MetaService` implementation and in `c.war` I have the `View` class, which would like to use these implementations.

But as you would expect, the injected `Instance` is empty (not null tho). Is there a way to find the remote bean references in my injected `Instance` instance, even though these implementations are in separate applications?

One important thing is that in the `View` class I don't know and don't care about the number of these implementations, nor the names of the applications they are deployed in. So there is no way for me to use specific JNDI strings to get these references.

P.S.: Should I try and use technologies like JMS instead? So that I call the method `add` on a JMS proxy, which sends out the requests and waits for answers from all the applications that implement said interface?

P.S.: To clarify, the reason I need this is actually so that I can get data of running services on my application server(s). I updated the example interface and implementations, so that it's more clear. Also, it would be nice, if I could get these metadata synchronously, so JMS is not neccessarily prefered, however I can probably make it work.

Comment: You probably need to annotate your interface with the **Remote** annotation since it is supposed to be accessed "remotely" (or from a different jvm). That being said the question stands as to how would the **Inject** resolves which of the two beans it would reference

Comment: Modern applications tend to go for more standard interfaces for remote APIs, particularly REST or gRPC. This makes writing components in different languages practical, and tooling is available to help debugging both sides of the interaction.

Comment: hy @alainlompo, in my actual project I have the annotation on. Unfortunately, in this case it doesn't make a difference. As for the other part of your comment, the point of using `Instance` is so that I don't have to decide which implementation I want to use, because I need all of them.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I don't really see how I can use a REST api to communicate with any number of services (presumably 2 or more, but we, of course, don't know during compile time). Maybe gRPC is a solution for this? I have never heard of it

Comment: I updated the original question to better clarify my goal

Comment: The way to do that is some variety of "service discovery", which is one of the things the EJB remoting is providing. Standard approaches today include Eureka, Consul, and Kubernetes routing (either using the internal general router or a mesh like Istio).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to convince myself to move away from remote EJBs. Well, it was also thanks to @chrylis-onstrike- as well, however, I'll opt for using JMS for this purpose.

The reason is that I can broadcast a request for the different services I need data from on-demand, enabling me to check for new services going online, or services failing.

Thanks to everyone who spent time trying to help me out.